# How do I get the mouse position when using a UWP InkCanvas

Tags: c#, uwp

I am writing a program using `C# UWP` where I have an `Inkcanvas` covering the whole screen. Without disabling this InkCanvas I would like to get the mouse position. I have tried to set an event like this:

```
MyInkCanvas.PointerMoved += MyInkCanvas_PointerMoved;
```

However, this event never gets called because I am guessing it is handled by the InkCanvas. Instead I tried to do the following:

```
MyInkCanvas.addHandler(PointerMovedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(MyInkCanvas_PointerMoved), true);
```

This does not work either which probably means I am doing something wrong because the documentation for AddHandler says:

> Adds a routed event handler for a specified routed event, adding the handler to the handler collection on the current element. Specify handledEventsToo as true to have the provided handler be invoked even if the event is handled elsewhere

If I understand correctly this should make the event happening even though the InkCanvas handles it first.

I have also tried to put this code on the InkCanvas parents with the same result.

So, How do I get the mouse position without disabling the InkCanvas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirement, you could get the mouse position via [`WetStrokeContinuing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.core.corewetstrokeupdatesource) event. It occurs after the `InkPresenter` starts processing an ink stroke and before it stops processing the same stroke, indicating ink data continues to be captured. You could get `coreWetStrokeUpdateSource` with the following code and 
subscribe to the `WetStrokeContinuing` event.

```
CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource coreWetStrokeUpdateSource = CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource.Create(MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter);

coreWetStrokeUpdateSource.WetStrokeContinuing += CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource_WetStrokeContinuing;
```

You will get the mouse position in the `WetStrokeContinuing` event handler.

```
private void CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource_WetStrokeContinuing(CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource sender, CoreWetStrokeUpdateEventArgs args)
{
    var points = args.NewInkPoints;
    foreach (var point in points)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"-----{ point.Position.X}--- {point.Position.Y}--");
    }
}
```

You could also use `PointerEventArgs` to get position, The difference between the two is that the trigger time is different.

```
private void StrokeInput_StrokeContinued(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkStrokeInput sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    var position = args.CurrentPoint.Position;
    Debug.WriteLine($"-----{ position.X}--- {position.Y}--");
}
```

The `StrokeContinued` Occurs when stroke input has started  and continues to be captured by an Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkPresenter object.

The `WetStrokeContinuing` occurs after the Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkPresenter starts processing an ink
stroke and before it stops processing the same stroke, indicating ink data continues to be captured.

The result is same. However, The `StrokeContinued` is more convenient to use.

Comment: This works very nice. A quick question though: I found out that I can also use `MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeInput.StrokeContinued += StrokeInput_StrokeContinued` which seams to me does the same thing. Do you know if there is any specific differences between these two that should make one better than the other for my case?